# Query inlining vs. flattening

Tags: sql, postgresql, optimization, query-optimization, query-planner

I've been digging the Internet over and over and couldn't find any reasonable answer. What's the difference between inlining and flattening in SQL query? I do actually use both interchangeably, eventually they lead to the same result - a big single query not many atomic ones.
But maybe there is a difference in definitions? For instance inline refer only to [functions](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.help.sqlanywhere.11.0.1/dbusage_en11/semantic-queryoptimization.html) and flattening means convert subquery to join only as stands [here](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.dc20022_1251/html/monitoring/X39732.htm)? But in another source one can find an example of [completely different transformation](https://my.vertica.com/docs/7.0.x/HTML/Content/Authoring/ProgrammersGuide/Queries/FlatteningFROMClauseSubqueriesAndViews.htm).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess there may be slight differences in how “inlining” and “flattening” are defined by people, but the way these terms are normally understood in the PostgreSQL community is that *inlining* is to pull the definition of a `LANGUAGE sql` function into the main query, and *flattening* is to transform a subquery or view into something else than a subquery, for example a join.

Comment: thank you Laurenz, but with flattening - does it have to be a join? I've seen some definitions that say it is a join but other sources claim it can be another construct: https://my.vertica.com/docs/7.0.x/HTML/Content/Authoring/ProgrammersGuide/Queries/FlatteningFROMClauseSubqueriesAndViews.htm

Comment: Point taken. I have edited the answer to be more general.